# Visual Studio 2012 PowerShell project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, powershell, azure, visual-studio-2012

We are using PowerShell for provisioning/configuration/patching of virtual machines on the Windows Azure platform. Are there any project templates available to manage PowerShell projects in Visual Studio 2012 through which I can manage these scripts?

I would like to be able to create

- PowerShell project with-in VS 2012 and add script files to it
- Have basic syntax-coloring and highlighting (good to have intellisense).
- Manage scripts using source control

I have found this visual studio extension [PowerGUI VSX](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/) but it works only for VS 2010.

**Updated [09/25/2013]** : Found [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597). It provides all the features mentioned above for working with PowerShell Projects in VS 2012

Comment: Unfortunately the PowerGUI VSX addin does not work with the latest version of PowerGUI (3.5).  So you'll either have to downgrade your installed version of PowerGUI, or wait for the VSX to be updated (which I have no news on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't get much Visual Studio love. How about the [PowerShell ISE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa), or [PowerShell Plus](https://www.idera.com/Free-Tools/PowerShell-Plus/)?

Of the three, the last is the only one with any source control integration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's unfortunate that even in VS 2012 there is no PowerShell integration. I am now considering to use VS 2010 with PowerGUI VSX

Comment: You can use PowerGUI with Visual Studio 2012: http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/powershell-and-visual-studio-2012/11937/

Answer (score 0):

There is another component in the Microsoft gallery for PowerShell integration in Visual Studio 2012; [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e3f9d3bf-e630-4b3e-968a-f86ac67b836c).